# gem installed, but still get: error file to import not found or unreadable: compass

Tags: sass, gruntjs, prestashop-1.6, compass

I am trying to compile `.scss` files of a Prestashop template locally using `grunt-contrib-sass`. It is configured as following:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '_theme/themes/swat-theme/sass',
            src: ['*.scss'],
            dest: '../css',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
},
```

but I get the following error message:

```
error file to import not found or unreadable: compass
    on line 1 of _theme/themes/swat-theme/sass/addresses.scss
```

I found out I had to install compass on my Windows 7 PC, which I did with `gem install compass`. All went fine. I checked with `compass --version` and it returns 1.0.3.

But, when I run `grunt sass` again, I still get the same error message. The beginning of the `addresses.scss` file is:

```
@import "compass";
@import "theme_variables";
```

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding an option:

```
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                compass: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '_theme/themes/swat-theme/sass',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: '../css',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    },
```